# How to save image after add text to an Image

Tags: php, gd

In order to add text to an image I'm using below code from a site

```
<?php
    //Set the Content Type
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    // Create Image From Existing File
    $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('sunset.jpg');

    // Allocate A Color For The Text
    $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

    // Set Path to Font File
    $font_path = 'font.TTF';

    // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
    $text = "This is a sunset!";

    // Print Text On Image
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

    // Send Image to Browser
    imagejpeg($jpg_image);

    // Clear Memory
    imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

It is working well but I am unable to save in pic for text file saving i am using this 
function

```
function write($post,$myFile){
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $post);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Is there any way I can able to save image in jpg ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my own code and working well! Just change the name of **name.jpg** to the **file name what you want**:

```
    <?php
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('sunset.jpg');
//$jpg_image=imagecreatetruecolor(100,100);

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
 $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);


  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'font1.TTF';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!";

  // Print Text On Image
  $x=20;
  for($i=0;$i<=strlen($text);$i++){
   $print_text=substr($text,$i,1);
   $x+=20;
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 30, 0, $x, 200, $white, $font_path, $print_text);
  }


  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image,'name.jpg');

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

My code is a little different with yours, one of different is You didn't change the place of pointer, the place that you are going to put your character  **I mean the $x**:

```
imagettftext($jpg_image, 30, 0, $x, 200, $white, $font_path, $print_text);
```

And another different is character, You gave the string *(not character)* to the **imagettftext** function, But I give one character. I think character is better than string In particular to creating captcha.

Answer (score 4):

Check this code. It's the same as your code, only difference is

`imagejpeg($jpg_image,"imagefolderpath/image.jpg");`

instead of `imagejpeg($jpg_image);`
Maybe it's helpful to you.

```html
<?php
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('sunset.jpg');
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
  $font_path = 'font.TTF';
  $text = "This is a sunset!";
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);
  imagejpeg($jpg_image,"imagefolderpath/image.jpg");
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To save the image in a file instead of outputting it, just change the line `imagejpeg($jpg_image);` to `imagejpeg($jpg_image, 'yourfile.jpg');` (you can also remove the `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` in this case).